# appwidget animation in an infinite loop

Tags: android

I want to use animation on my appwidget in a loop. 
I've defined my translate animation via xml and added android:repeatMode="restart" on 'set', but nothing happens, the animation runs once and then stops. According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html) it should be pushed down.

Example

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:repeatMode="restart">
     <alpha android:fromAlpha="0" android:toAlpha="1" android:duration="2000" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you are only using 1 animation, you don't need to use a `<set>`. Sets are used for multiple animations.
Try this:

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromAlpha="0"
    android:toAlpha="1"
    android:duration="2000" />
```

and in your activity:

```
Animation newsAnim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.news_animation);
newsAnim.reset();  // reset initialization state
newsAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
newsAnim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); // Or a number of times
TextView animatedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_animated);
animatedText.startAnimation(newsAnim);
```

This will invoke your animation, set the desired time / functions.
I have noticed that looping animations with a set isn't that easy like this.

EDIT: Should you need to use a `<set>` explicitly, then you can do the following:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="100%" android:toYDelta="-100%"
        android:duration="15000" android:zAdjustment="bottom"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:repeatCount="-1" />

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="4" android:toXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="3" android:toYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="15000"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:repeatCount="-1" />
</set>
```

Note the duration of all the animations. Keep them the same if you want a consistent animation..

Hope this helps.
Yours truly,

Nyllian

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I'm trying to animate an appwidget, not a regular activity, therefore I don't have any access to AnimationUtils.